# Replacing Exhaust Fan in Bathroom and connecting to semi rigid aluminum duct

Tags: bathtub, exhaust-fan

I am replacing my exhaust fan in the bathroom and having a hard time connecting the new fan to the aluminum semi rigid duct, because is hard to compress, extend or curve.  How can I make this easier ?

thank you

Comment: Duct tape could be your friend to help seal it. Get the good stuff so it will hold and seal.

Comment: Since we are not talking about grease (stove vent) or lint (dryer vent), is flexible (but non-flamable) duct work acceptable under the building code?